# How to get distinct count of a column based on value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

How to get distinct count of a column based on value of another column?

I could understand that this could be achieved by creating another intermediate table but I am running this query on table with billions of rows,so it would be better if we could get result in one query rather than creating another grouping.

Here is the sample creation code of testing.

```
CREATE TABLE MYGROUP ( Category,PERSON,Flag ) AS
          SELECT 'Cat1','A','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','A','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','B','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','B','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','B','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','B','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','B','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat3','X','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat3','Y','0' FROM DUAL;
```

Desired Output:

```
Category    Count of Distinct Persons with Flag =1
Cat1        2
Cat2        1
Cat3        0
```

Reason of output
There both A and  B with Flag =1 so count is 2 in first row 
and There is only B with Flag =1 so count is 1 in second row
Cat3 count is 0 as there are no row with Flag =1

Comment: You've listed nearly every database out there; which one are you actually using?

Comment: Its for oracle , added others as it might be similar to others as well.

Comment: No, the answer you accepted would not run on MySQL at all, and also wouldn't run on SQL Server because it doesn't have a `DECODE()` function.  In the future, just tag with your actual database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct decode(flag,1,person,null))`

It will ignore persons where flag not equal to "1" and will work faster

```
select  category ,count (distinct decode(flag,1,person,null)) countof from MYGROUP
group by category
```

Or You can use  analytic function `Over (partition by )`  clause

In General analytic functions works faster.  Here is example how you can apply analytic function for this question:

```
select distinct  category ,count (distinct decode(flag,1,person,null)) over (partition by category) countof from MYGROUP
```

Look on execution plan and choose whats  better for you

Comment: `and will work faster` ... I doubt this would be faster than a `WHERE` clause if the `Flag` column is indexed.

Comment: May be, we can see it on  execution plan

Comment: Amazing solution ,First solution seemed more clear to me Thanks!, I think the distinct key word in second solution make it little inefficient than the first one.

Comment: Yes , in second solution two distinct expression , but in some case it can be faster than 1st one, because analityc functions works very faster than simple grouping

Answer (score 2):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT PERSON)`:

```
SELECT Category,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN PERSON END) AS distinct_count
FROM MYGROUP
GROUP BY Category
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle